# Scheduled tasks python running with IDLE(python GUI) Windows server 2012

Tags: python, windows-server-2012, python-idle, taskmanager

How do I set up task manager to run my python script using IDLE (Python GUI) or python windows shell?

Comment: IDLE is an IDE meant for developing programs, not for running them in production use.  Just run your script with python.exe and whatever arguments needed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like i dont need to run my python script on python windows shell,,i just removed any `print`s that would display on `cmd` or `shell` and instead store them in variables then set my task scheduler

Program/Script:

```
C:\python27\python.exe
```

Add Arguments:

```
[my script including its directory] C:\scrape.py
```